# Restricted access to specific commands from the server side

Tags: cpanel

When accessed through SSH from PuTTY terminal, certain types of commands are restricted only in cPanel. Why is that happening?

```
login as: nishanth
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Passphrase for key "imported-openssh-key":
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ echo "$PATH"
/home/nishanth/ruby/gems/bin:/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/home/nishanth/bin
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ sudo -s
-bash: sudo: command not found
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ man --help
-bash: man: command not found
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ man man
-bash: man: command not found
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 815327 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 819966 pts/1    00:00:00 cat
 829035 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
 [nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ lsb_release -a
-bash: lsb_release: command not found
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ hostnamectl
-bash: hostnamectl: command not found
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ uname -r
2.6.32-673.26.1.lve1.4.27.el6.x86_64
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-673.26.1.lve1.4.27.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun May 7 19:22:54 EDT 2017
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ uname -a
Linux bh-in-28.webhostbox.net 2.6.32-673.26.1.lve1.4.27.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun May 7 19:22:54 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-673.26.1.lve1.4.27.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun May 7 19:22:54 EDT 2017
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ cat /proc/redhat-release
cat: /proc/redhat-release: No such file or directory
[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$
```

Since Red Hat 4.4.7-18 is an linux built.

> bash: some_command: command not found

why does bash prompts saying command not found?

Comment: The server is running cloudlinux?